# HTML, CSS, JQuery On Windows Forms?

Tags: .net, winforms, webui

is there a way to use HTML, CSS And JQuery on a Windows Forms Application

and be a good looking GUI. and the code will be VB.NET or C#.NET ?

Comment: This is called a *web* application. It runs in a web browser, not a Windows application. They are two completely different technologies, each with their own use cases. Pick the one that is most appropriate for you. Don't mix and match, the result is quite poor.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to add a [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to your form.  You can use it to display a web page (HTML, CSS, and JavaScript).

You can interact with the loaded HTML document using the WebBrowser's [Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [ObjectForScripting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties.

Comment: how to handle controls events ? and Execute the code.

Comment: This works well, and there are alternatives to the plain vanilla IE web control (Chrome CEF, Awesomium, etc). HTML and CSS can be stored as embedded resources if necessary. You can hook resource loading and navigation. Etc.